# 'wdm' Gem on Windows 8.1 x64 Ruby 2.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to learn how to do testing with Rspec, Capybara & Guard. This requires me to install wdm gem as well to work with guard listener on windows.

For some reason its failing.

Can someone tell me what is happening here? This is a bit out of my league. The wdm gem for some reason is not installing:

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  # Testing stuff
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'wdm'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

what happens when I bundle install:

```
$ bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.2
Using minitest 5.6.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.0.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.1
Using rack 1.6.0
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.1
Using globalid 0.3.5
Using activejob 4.2.1
Using mime-types 2.5
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.1
Using activemodel 4.2.1
Using arel 6.0.0
Using activerecord 4.2.1
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bundler 1.9.4
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using byebug 4.0.5
Using xpath 2.0.0
Using capybara 2.4.4
Using hitimes 1.2.2
Using timers 4.0.1
Using celluloid 0.16.0
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using ffi 1.9.8
Using formatador 0.2.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.4
Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
Using listen 2.10.0
Using lumberjack 1.0.9
Using nenv 0.2.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Using notiffany 0.0.6
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using slop 3.6.0
Using win32console 1.3.2
Using pry 0.10.1
Using guard 2.12.5
Using guard-compat 1.2.1
Using rspec-support 3.2.2
Using rspec-core 3.2.3
Using rspec-expectations 3.2.1
Using rspec-mocks 3.2.1
Using rspec 3.2.0
Using guard-rspec 4.5.0
Using multi_json 1.11.0
Using jbuilder 2.2.13
Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
Using sprockets 3.0.2
Using sprockets-rails 2.2.4
Using rails 4.2.1
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using rspec-rails 3.2.1
Using sass 3.4.13
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.10
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using tzinfo-data 1.2015.4
Using uglifier 2.7.1

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150425-10244-tjzt35.rb extconf.rb

extconf failed, uncaught signal 11

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/wdm-0.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/wdm-0.1.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing wdm (0.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install wdm -v '0.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed Devkit,if you did not,[downloads](http://d29vzk4ow07wi7.cloudfront.net/cd467f4d02d60c6cf78069c59d7ff114d93426f9?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe%22&Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOiBbeyJSZXNvdXJjZSI6Imh0dHAqOi8vZDI5dnprNG93MDd3aTcuY2xvdWRmcm9udC5uZXQvY2Q0NjdmNGQwMmQ2MGM2Y2Y3ODA2OWM1OWQ3ZmYxMTRkOTM0MjZmOT9yZXNwb25zZS1jb250ZW50LWRpc3Bvc2l0aW9uPWF0dGFjaG1lbnQlM0JmaWxlbmFtZSUzRCUyMkRldktpdC1taW5ndzY0LTY0LTQuNy4yLTIwMTMwMjI0LTE0MzItc2Z4LmV4ZSUyMiIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTQzMDAyNjc3N30sIklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIwLjAuMC4wLzAifX19XX0_&Signature=VFWgJONMn8XqrtHzhiOYUOZhAYVzBrbyESPNdoqqiRg4xQyng7vHNcjFK96tA0YWt1ugBd-xh1349UZ~S-ke8EseHheQ0-YVBltb48aLfsoxR6D8J86DIgh6zZWbikNJfPzlBH7GeE4qjqXEt0fz-MsEFtZ4UZW1hFHeUar7oFb9qvsi3A~~keVpeMDgcnPUP5-fRdY56vkgyyN-udP07kiJC0HHtr4YbylVRhXMToMtK9lTOHnBfcdPlgJoTmDh8dp1ReqgcuQonGuRmy7uIgWQJmjadMGTMA4Vv3x13CRsObybj6cX2nokbJ~8~8xZ5ZeVb3UY9soc3eQnoGND5Q__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIFKFWOMXM2UMTSFA) DevKit, Then Click Extract and wait until the process is finished.Next, you need to initialize the DevKit and bind it to your Ruby installation. Open your favorite command line tool and navigate to the folder you extracted the DevKit into.Auto-detect Ruby installations and add them to a configuration file for the next step.

```
ruby dk.rb init
```

Install the DevKit, binding it to your Ruby installation.

```
ruby dk.rb install
```

Comment: I already have DevKit that is not the problem... Not sure how to fix

Answer (score 0):

run

```
gem install wdm -v '0.1.0'
bundle install
bundle update
```

If you get error just check which gem needs to be installed and install it.But I would recommend RailsInstaller.

Note: RailsInstaller is the best package for installing rails on windows.I have tried it on windows8 works great.It includes all required Packages. RilasInstaller - http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: have you run gem install wdm -v '0.1.0'

Comment: where you able to install the gem ? if not what is the error ?

Comment: ```Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)```